# Java Decryption Missing Text

Tags: java, encryption, file-io

I tried to encrypt and decrypt a .txt file. The encryption worked fine but when I decrypt it the .txt file is empty. Here is my code:

```
package crypto;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class MyCrypto
{
    SecretKeySpec key;
    Cipher cipher;
    byte[] iv = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    MyCrypto() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        key =new SecretKeySpec("22042016".getBytes(), "DES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    }

    public void encrypt(File file) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

         byte[] block = new byte[8];
         int i;
         while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
         cos.write(block, 0, i);
         }
     cos.close();
     fis.close();
    }

    public void decrypt(File file) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] block = new byte[8];
         int i;
        while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) {
        fos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
        cis.close();
        fos.close();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    {
        MyCrypto crypto = new MyCrypto();
        File cryptoFile = new File(".../crypto.txt");
        crypto.encrypt(cryptoFile);
        crypto.decrypt(cryptoFile);
    }
}
```

I know that DES isn't very safe. But it's just for my trying to mess around with de- and encryption.

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: Thank you. But it is only for encrypting a save file for a game so that nobody can mess around with it and modify their progress. But could you please explain why I need two seperate files?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code in your decrypt method with this:

```
        // write decrypted bytes
        fos.write(cipher.doFinal(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())));
        // close the output file
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: It would be better to use *two* `File` references instead of one.

Comment: See Artjom's comment.  Try using separate file references for the encrypted/decrypted files.

Comment: Could you explain your idea a little more. For what should I use the first and for what the second file. And I also got an BadPadded exception at doFinal().

Comment: Make sure you are still calling the init method to set the cipher to decrypt mode prior to my sample code.  The two file references might look something like this public void decrypt(File encryptedFile, File decryptedFile) - where the FileOutputStream is created for the decryptedFile and the encryptedFile replaces "file" in my code.

Comment: I've got it like this. But I still get a Badpadded exception.

Comment: @NovaShadowflame You forgot to pass in the IV during encryption which will result in a random IV.